# Python/Django model dictionary allows one type of update, but not another

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working on some Django/Python code.

Basically, the backend of my code gets sent a dict of parameters named 'p'.  These values all come off Django models.

When I tried to override them as such:

```
p['age']=25
```

I got a 'model error'.  Yet, if I write:

```
p.age=25
```

it works fine.

My suspicion is that, internally, choice #1 tries to set a new value to an instance of a class created by Django that objects to being overridden, but internally Python3 simply replaces the Django instance with a "new" attribute of the same name ('age'), without regard for the prior origin, type, or class of what Django created.

All of this is in a RESTful framework, and actually in test code.  So even if I am right I don't believe it changes anything for me in reality.

But can anyone explain why one type of assignment to an existing dict works, and the other fails?

Comment: What is the result of **`print(type(p))`** ?

Comment: What is "model error"? Please paste in the full error message.

Comment: You will need to provide the full code. What *exactly* is p, and where does it come from? If `p.age` works but `p['age']` doesn't, then p is definitely not a dict.

Comment: I mis-spoke, and that is no doubt the problem.  Owing to Django 'magic', p is a class, not a dict (though it may build of the dict class) and elements are themselves classes, not

Answer (score 0):

p is a class, not a dict.  Django built it that way.

But, as such, one approach (p.age) lets you change an attribute of the object in the class.